# Чтение с файла с определённой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-faq

У меня есть текстовый файл и мне нужно считать всю информацию, которая расположена после 25-й строки.

Как это сделать? Пожалуйста, помогите!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for i in range(25):
        f.readline()
    # в x будет 26 строка
    x = f.readline()
```

Answer (score 15):

Если небольшой файл, можно список строк получить и отбросить первые 25:

```
lines = file.readlines()[25:]
```

Если файл большой, то чтобы не читать его весь сразу, можно воспользоваться тем что file является итератором на строками, разделёнными "\n":

```
from itertools import islice

lines = islice(file, 25, None)
```

в этом случае `lines` не список, а итератор возвращающий строки из файла при его обходе, начиная с 26-ой строки, где `file = open(filename)`.

Answer (score 2):

Например, можно сделать так:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
lines = ''.join(lines[25:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
for linenum,line in enumerate(open('D:/file.txt','r+')):
    if linenum>24:
        print (line.strip())
```

если исключительно считать, а не вывести, то вместо последней строки x=line

Comment: 1- `+` в режим не нужно добавлять, если не пишете/читаете из файла одновременно. 2- код у вас с 27 строки начинает печатать.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("something.txt") as infile:
    for __ in range(25):
        next(infile)
    for row in infile:
        print(row)
```

Объяснение:

1. `infile` - это *итератор*, потому  к нему возможно применить стандартную функцию `next()` для выдачи (или пропуска) следующей строки файла.
2. В первом цикле его переменная не используется — потому я (традиционно) применил для неё странное имя `__`.
3. После перехода первым циклом в итераторе `infile` уже первых 25 строк нет, потому второй цикл выдает только остальные строки файла.