# Как прочитать определенную линию в txt файле

Tags: python, pyautogui

я делаю бота который сам заполняет строки на сайтах

```
if choice == 'znzv':
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        pg.typewrite(f.readline(1))
```

я думал этот код выводит первую строку моего txt файла. Помогите пожалуйста выводить определенные строки

Comment: Надо не "думал", а читать документацию. Убери число и будет первая строка.

Answer (score 1):

Число, передаваемое в скобки `readline`, – это количество байт, которые нужно считать. Об этом написано и в документации и в любом пособии по Python.

А если хотя бы немного погуглить, а не писать сразу на SO, можно найти [чуть ли не дубликат Вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/601559/344284) (считаю, что всё-таки не дубликат, потому отвечаю). И там приведено два прекрасных способа считать из файла строку с номером N. Учитывая Ваш код, вот первый из них:

```py
if choice == 'znzv':
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        pg.typewrite(f.readlines()[N]))
```

Здесь читается N-ная строка. Второй способ, думаю, лучше не использовать, если заранее доподлинно не известно количество строк в файле.